# Approach to create dynamic XSL-FO

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo

I need to create comples XSL-FO file that will be used latter for creating pdf file.

There is a requirement to insert n-tables, each table can have different structure (e.g. number of headers, number of rows, nu,ber of columns).

All relevant info is available on runtime only, so it's not possible to create the structure before.

What can you suggest?

Update:

I guess the only option is to construct the xsl-fo file with FileWriter.
Based on the requirements.

Comment: Where does the "relevant info"/structure come from? In what form is it available?

Comment: mzjn, come as xml file. Node that represent table type, also has attribute with number of columns/rows, number of headers,sub headers and etc.

Comment: Why is constructing the FO file with FileWriter the only option? Why can't you use XSLT, for example?

Answer (score 0):

create a bean class to hold variables and arraylists used in your pdf creator.  Create a JAXBContext using this populated bean.  In your xlst file use

```
<xsl:for-each select="myArrListofTableRows">
```

Comment: You didn't understand me, I need to generate xlst itself, base on some input.

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking about XSL-FO generation based on some external parameter from JAVA file. Am I right?

Comment: @Yuris, So you want totally random input to produce totally random output.  Or can you think about it and try to model your input which can be transformed using xlst (The XSLT processor takes one or more XML source documents, plus one or more XSLT stylesheet modules, and processes them to produce an output document.)  An anaology of what you are asking (I think) is to generate CSS at runtime.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @user2310289, this is true. The "overall" pattern  is known. There can be 5-7 types of tables each type have a different look. But number of tables, size of each table and order of the tables is now known

Comment: But still, can you not model it as a collection of tables and each table has a collection of columns / rows?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem to create dynamic PDF on the basis of provided parameters. You just need to create some global parameters with your XSLT and write XSLT code by manipulating those parameters. And if, there are 5-7 types of tables which are different from each other, Java must provide some flag or parameter to XSLT to know what needs to be generated. You may also look some configuration file (e.g., config.xml) to reflect your XSL-FO output regarding page size, font, or whatever else

Comment: @Navin Rawat, I think you are going to a right direction. But how can I inject those parameters to xsl-fo? i don't think some thing of this is exist. I mean it's not possible to do: if (numOfColumns =3 ) then Create3Columns()

Comment: I was thinking of creating the xsl-fo by using stingbuilder and actually writing the code of xsl-fo to a file from scratch!!!

Comment: there is no if(numberOfColumns -3) but there is <xsl:if>.  As per my original answer (using xsl:for-each), I am producing PDF including an unknown of images into a PDF file as columns and rows (like a photo proof sheet)

Comment: xsl:for-each is good for adding rows to a table how can I use this to create a new table?